How to send data from consumer snowflake account to provider snowflake account
I am a new beginner to Snowflake, working on building a Snowflake native app. Forgive me if I mentioned anything wrong. My question is how can I send the data other than logs from the consumer snowflake account to the provider snowflake account using the snowflake native app?
In my research when we create a shared view from the provider snowflake account it is only readable from the consumer side and not able to insert or delete the data to it. so we providers can send data to the consumer using this technique. we can send the logs via the event table and share them with the provider but I do not want to share the sensitive data via logs using the event table, you can also do it via API Integration where I have to create a few APIs and call the API from the consumer snowflake account using the native app and send the data, I do not want to use this because then I have to setup the authorization and authentication features to secure the API endpoints. we can send the data if we have the Snowflake credentials of the provider account but that is not the best way to do it, other than these ways could you please share any techniques, documentation, videos, or tutorials that discuss sending data from consumer to provider snowflake account using a native app?

Sharing back to a provider requires your consumer to take action and either setup their own native app to share data back to you OR create a share and share the requested data back to the original provider.  There is a wonderful framework called the Solution Install Wizard (https://developers.snowflake.com/solution/accelerate-the-deployment-of-snowflake-native-code-using-solution-installation-wizard/) that you could integrate into your native app to walk your consumers through a share setup.
